# Minikube tunnel doesn't start without any log

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubectl, minikube

I'm on MacOS and I have the following minikube & kubectl

```
minikube version
minikube version: v1.24.0
commit: 76b94fb3c4e8ac5062daf70d60cf03ddcc0a741b

kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.3", GitCommit:"c92036820499fedefec0f847e2054d824aea6cd1", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-10-27T18:41:28Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.3", GitCommit:"c92036820499fedefec0f847e2054d824aea6cd1", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-10-27T18:35:25Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

And here is my ingress-service.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: "/"
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: client-cluster-ip-service
                port:
                  number: 3000
          - path: "/api"
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: server-cluster-ip-service
                port:
                  number: 5000
```

```
kubectl get ingress
NAME              CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
ingress-service   <none>   *                 80      8h
```

At this point, if I run `minikube tunnel` it doesn't start without any error.
It doesn't even ask me the sudo permission.

```
minikube tunnel
❗  The service/ingress ingress-service requires privileged ports to be exposed: [80 443]
  sudo permission will be asked for it.
  Starting tunnel for service ingress-service.
```

```
minikube tunnel --alsologtostderr
I1206 23:54:01.354781    3062 out.go:297] Setting OutFile to fd 1 ...
I1206 23:54:01.355084    3062 out.go:349] isatty.IsTerminal(1) = true
I1206 23:54:01.355091    3062 out.go:310] Setting ErrFile to fd 2...
I1206 23:54:01.355097    3062 out.go:349] isatty.IsTerminal(2) = true
I1206 23:54:01.355182    3062 root.go:313] Updating PATH: /Users/mac/.minikube/bin
I1206 23:54:01.355348    3062 mustload.go:65] Loading cluster: minikube
I1206 23:54:01.355625    3062 config.go:176] Loaded profile config "minikube": Driver=docker, ContainerRuntime=docker, KubernetesVersion=v1.22.3
I1206 23:54:01.355999    3062 cli_runner.go:115] Run: docker container inspect minikube --format={{.State.Status}}
I1206 23:54:01.478018    3062 host.go:66] Checking if "minikube" exists ...
I1206 23:54:01.478322    3062 cli_runner.go:115] Run: docker container inspect -f "'{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "8443/tcp") 0).HostPort}}'" minikube
I1206 23:54:01.595426    3062 api_server.go:165] Checking apiserver status ...
I1206 23:54:01.595706    3062 ssh_runner.go:152] Run: sudo pgrep -xnf kube-apiserver.*minikube.*
I1206 23:54:01.595808    3062 cli_runner.go:115] Run: docker container inspect -f "'{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "22/tcp") 0).HostPort}}'" minikube
I1206 23:54:01.712329    3062 sshutil.go:53] new ssh client: &{IP:127.0.0.1 Port:32772 SSHKeyPath:/Users/mac/.minikube/machines/minikube/id_rsa Username:docker}
I1206 23:54:01.807426    3062 ssh_runner.go:152] Run: sudo egrep ^[0-9]+:freezer: /proc/1927/cgroup
I1206 23:54:01.815516    3062 api_server.go:181] apiserver freezer: "7:freezer:/docker/73b947e56809dda4593fa02cb28844a814fe473c1451f63c0a08e7b6d82e933d/kubepods/burstable/pod5a60ad17d917e03c0e9b4ca796aa9460/4f86ee5215a023007e227ac4a481f310a300148102ecb298073389435733e09a"
I1206 23:54:01.815635    3062 ssh_runner.go:152] Run: sudo cat /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/docker/73b947e56809dda4593fa02cb28844a814fe473c1451f63c0a08e7b6d82e933d/kubepods/burstable/pod5a60ad17d917e03c0e9b4ca796aa9460/4f86ee5215a023007e227ac4a481f310a300148102ecb298073389435733e09a/freezer.state
I1206 23:54:01.822325    3062 api_server.go:203] freezer state: "THAWED"
I1206 23:54:01.822361    3062 api_server.go:240] Checking apiserver healthz at https://127.0.0.1:32769/healthz ...
I1206 23:54:01.828697    3062 api_server.go:266] https://127.0.0.1:32769/healthz returned 200:
ok
I1206 23:54:01.828718    3062 tunnel.go:57] Checking for tunnels to cleanup...
I1206 23:54:01.832267    3062 cli_runner.go:115] Run: docker container inspect -f "'{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "22/tcp") 0).HostPort}}'" minikube
I1206 23:54:01.965147    3062 out.go:176] ❗  The service/ingress ingress-service requires privileged ports to be exposed: [80 443]
❗  The service/ingress ingress-service requires privileged ports to be exposed: [80 443]
I1206 23:54:01.967937    3062 out.go:176]   sudo permission will be asked for it.
  sudo permission will be asked for it.
I1206 23:54:01.970767    3062 out.go:176]   Starting tunnel for service ingress-service.
  Starting tunnel for service ingress-service.
```

Comment: "It doesn't start without any error".   You mean it starts with an error?

Comment: No, I wait over 30 mins but it doesn't start.

Comment: Can you add the following option for more details on error: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/troubleshooting/#enabling-debug-logs

Comment: @nitishagar I've added `--alsologtostderr` option output.

Comment: Unfortunately, I wasn't able to reproduce this but I came across a very similar issue running `istio-system` here: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/10085#issuecomment-949360206

Comment: Which [minikube driver](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/) are you using?

Comment: @MikolajS. How can I check which minikube driver I use?

Comment: I just found in the logs that it is standard `docker` drive (in your `minikube tunnel --alsologtostderr` command). Anyway, something is wrong with your Ingress - the address is missing. How did you install Nginx Ingress controller to your cluster? If you didn't install it, could you follow docs [from Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/#enable-the-ingress-controller) and then check?

Comment: I installed Nginx ingress controller by the docs before

Comment: Could you run `kubectl get ingressclass` and paste the output?

Comment: it says "No resources found"

Comment: Could you please apply this yaml -> https://pastebin.com/J5jPD2Ku and check if you get IP address in the command `kubectl get ingress`? If there will be an address, could you try again `minikube tunnel` ? Please let know the results.

Comment: I applied that yaml file but it doesn't show ip after kubectl get ingress. NAME              CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
ingress-service   <none>   *                 80      11d

Comment: Did you try to re-apply ingress resource (`kubectl delete` and `kubectl apply` commands)? If no, could you do that and check if there is an IP address? Could you please check if ingress controller pod is running (`kubectl get pods -n ingress-nginx` command, look for the pod name starting with `ingress-nginx-controller-{..}`)? Could you then check logs for this pod using this command -> `kubectl logs ingress-nginx-controller-{..} -n ingress-nginx`?